# ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.<init>(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:141)

Tags: java

First：this code has problem under more threads

```
@Override
public void onLoaded(List<Student> students) {
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onLoaded(students);
    }
}
```

Then change like this

```
@Override
public void onLoaded(List<Student> students) {
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Student> copyList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Student>(students);
    if(listener != null){
        if(copyList.size() > 0){
            listener.onLoaded(copyList);
        }else{
            listener.onLoaded(students);
        }
    }
}
```

this also has problem

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
     at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:136)
     at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.<init>(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:141)
```

in CopyOnWriteArrayList.java

```
/**
* Creates a new instance containing the elements of {@code collection}.
*/
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CopyOnWriteArrayList(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
    this((E[]) collection.toArray());
}
```

AbstractCollection implements Collection，in AbstractCollection

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
            return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}
```

finally，it is the problem .

I just know I can use Lock to fix it, but I do not know will it lead ANR in Android, I can not repeat the problem, how can I fix it?

Now I am trying to fix it like this, will it be ok?

```
@Override
public void onLoaded(List<Student> students) {
    final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Student> copyList;
    synchronized (students) {
        copyList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Student>(students);
    }
    if(listener != null){
        if(copyList.size() > 0){
            listener.onLoaded(copyList);
        }else{
            listener.onLoaded(students);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you're sharing a mutable ArrayList between multiple threads, without proper synchronization. Don't do that. With what you posted, we can't provide much better answers than that. Posting the code of the JDK isn't necessary: we have that code, too.

Comment: Our code is just a SDK, the problem is posted by Developers。 when user has a click, we will load the data and callback to the dev.

Comment: Then tell the Developers that they shouldn't share a mutable ArrayList between multiple threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: No, your fix won't be OK. If the code out of the SDK shares a List between threads without proper synchronization, the client code is faulty, and the client code is the one that must be fixed. The error happens in the constructor of CopyOnWriteArrayList, yet CopyOnWriteArrayList doesn't have a bug, and doesn't try to fix client errors by using synchronization. So your SDK shouldn't either.